# C pointer argument vs local copy

Tags: c

Is it more cache friendly to use a local copy of an argument than using the pointer argument directly? Will the overhead of copying outweigh the performance gained?
I guess it depends on the size of the copied data.

```
void foo(struct data *p) {
    /* Do stuff with p ... */
}

// VS

void bar(struct data *p) {
    struct data copy = *p;
    /* Do stuff with copy ... */
    *p = copy;
}
```

I'm asserting that "Do stuff" pushes a lot of other local variables on the stack.

Edit: Also, the data is supposed to be altered/initialized by the function.

Edit: Is this something the compiler might optimize?

Comment: …and on the compiler optimization settings, specifics of your hardware architecture, the relative position of Moon and Mars, etc. so, just measure it (or if you don't measure it, then it's probably not important enough for you to worry about its "performance").

Comment: This also depends on what you do with the data. So it depends. Benchmarking is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your operating systems ABI.

Let's assume for the moment that you're running a 64 bit Linux system. A pointer is an integer type and the first six integer types are passed by registers during your function call - no cache involvement so far.

If you go for your copy you assign extra RAM-space. In this case your cache is part of your whole program. 
I would go for the first one as it passes your pointer information directly and does not assign extra RAM.

But: If you like to measure your program. Go for valgrind (still assuming you're running linux).

Code both variants and do `valgrind --tool=cachegrind myfile` and compare the results. Though I really doubt that there's a difference on modern CPUs...

Comment: I'm going to cross-compile (from x64 Linux), so I didn't include any OS info. I'm already using valgrind so I might try that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there are so many variables involved here it's very difficult to consider them all, but let me try and outline a few important aspects:

1. whether you use the pointer or use a local copy instead should not make a difference from the cash memory's point of view: modern caches based architectures will have the data in the cache by the time you need it (unless your data structure is larder than a cache line - which is very unlikely)
2. There is a very good chance that the generated code in both cases is 95% the same: when you read or write a field in the from your data structure, the compiler reads it locally (either in a register or places it on the stack) anyway. The difference would come from reading/writing all data fields or just some of them.
3. Considering a modern day parallel CPU architecture the overhead might not even be there, actually in some cases, because the compiler is able to group the instructions better, the generated code for the situation where you use a local copy might be faster.